# Syncano Android SDK - Reference field in Class Object

Tags: java, android, syncano

I would like to use 'reference' type of field in my Class Object.
I'm not sure how to define it in Java POJO object - I tried setting String,Integer, int, and as well object that are defined in web Dashboard as reference class - I got failure when creating such object (however it is visible correctly in web Dashboard):

```
Response{resultCode=5, httpResultCode=201, error='Error parsing response. com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected an int but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 257 path $.userid', httpReasonPhrase='Created', data=null}
```

And if I put another object type there, app crashed with `Field type Xyz is not supported.`

My Class Object:

```
@SyncanoClass(name = "custom_obj")
public class CustomObj extends SyncanoObject {
    public static final String FIELD_TITLEID = "title";
    public static final String FIELD_USERID = "userid";

    @SyncanoField(name = FIELD_TITLEID)
    public String title;
    @SyncanoField(name = FIELD_USERID)
    public Integer userId;
}
```

Without setting userId - I get success response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes we know about this bug and is fixed on branch [Virtual Table support](https://github.com/Syncano/syncano-android/tree/feature/virtual_view_table_support). In next weekend should be merged to master and published. My answer below relates to this branch.

We decided to drop idea to store reference as `Integer` and replace it by `SyncanoObject` to allow easy access to object.

For example, if you download CustomObj all inner object (in example `YourSyncanoObject`) is collapsed - thats mean you get your object only with id, without all other fields. If you want more information about object you should call syncanoObject.fetch();

But if you want to expanded object we almost finish future similar to [Virtual Table](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp) with allow you get get your CustomObj with expanded inner syncano object fields.

```
@SyncanoClass(name = "custom_obj")
public class CustomObj extends SyncanoObject {
    public static final String FIELD_TITLEID = "title";
    public static final String FIELD_USERID = "userid";

    @SyncanoField(name = FIELD_TITLEID)
    public String title;
    @SyncanoField(name = FIELD_USERID)
    public YourSyncanoObject syncanoObject;
}
```

Comment: This is great :) Thanks. I also very like decision to move from Integers od id to pointers to objects itself - much much better.

Comment: New version (4.0.6) was released today and it is ready to use.